# .vimrc is not executed when opening a new tab in MacVim

Tags: macvim, janus

I've got MacVim and Janus installed.

I have recently added `set rnu` to my .vimrc.after to enable relative line numbering and found out that I only have rnu working when opening a new window. I mean, when I open a new tab in existing window, I get normal sequencial numbering.

I would like to know how can I enable rnu for all my MacVim windows and tabs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ran into the same problem. The reason is that absolute line numbers are being set for some filetypes. Hopefully the janus devs can do something about it: I just opened an issue for that on the github repo: https://github.com/carlhuda/janus/issues/472

**Update**:

Add this to your `~/.vimrc.after` file:

> set nonumber
>
> set relativenumber

Relative line numbers should persist with these settings.